# How to change the Find Panel in TexShop?

Tags: packages, mactex, mac, texshop

I run a TexShop v3.11 on a Mac OSX 10.8.2. The find panel of TexShop is set to be Ogrekit in Preferences. Then I quit TexShop and reopened it. But, when I use cmd+F in my editing document, the find panel is still the default Apple Find Panel.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I can't confirm the behavior.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mac settings more than anything TeX related.

Comment: I also note that it's not reproducible!